# Find latent variable using rSTAN

Tags: bayesian, factor-analysis, latent-variable, rstan

I have the following simulated data:

```
alpha = c(1,5,-5,0)
beta = c(1,2,-1,0)
n = 10^3
F <- rnorm(n,0,1) # define latent variable
x1 <- rnorm(n,alpha[1]*F+beta[1],1)
x2 <- rnorm(n,alpha[2]*F+beta[2],0.5)
x3 <- rnorm(n,alpha[3]*F+beta[3],5)
x4 <- rnorm(n,0,1)
df<-as.list(x1,x2,x3,x4,n);
```

I need to estimate the correlation matrix between predictors `x1..4` and recover parameters `alpha` and `beta`. For correlation matrix I found a way:

```
cor_model <-"
data{
    int n;
    vector[n] x4;
    vector[n] x3;
    vector[n] x2;
    vector[n] x1;
}
parameters{
    row_vector[4] mu;
    corr_matrix[4] Rho;
    vector<lower=0>[4] Sigma;
}
model{
    vector[4] YY[n];
    
    Sigma ~ exponential( 1 );
    Rho ~ lkj_corr( 4 );
    mu ~ normal( 0 , 1 );
    
    for ( j in 1:n ) YY[j] = [ x1[j] , x2[j] , x3[j] , x4[j] ]';
    YY ~ multi_normal( mu , quad_form_diag(Rho , Sigma) );
}
"
library(rstan)
m1 <-stan(model_code = cor_model,data =df)
```

But, I need to estimate `F` itself what is equal to `alpha` ans `beta` estimation as I understand. I read about Bayesian factor analysis but they use some packages for it and have too complicated examples for me. I tried this code:

```
X=cbind(x1,x2,x3,x4)
df2<-list(y=X,N = dim(X)[1], J = dim(X)[2])
fact_model <-'
data{
  int<lower=0> N;
  int<lower=0> J;
  matrix[N, J] y;
}
parameters{
  unit_vector[J] alpha;
  vector[J] beta;
  vector<lower=0>[J] sigma;
  vector[N] x;
  real<lower=0> x_sigma;
}
model{
  matrix[N,J] mu;
  x_sigma ~ normal(0, 1);
  alpha ~ normal(0, 10);
  beta ~ normal(0, 1);
  sigma ~ exponential(1);
  x ~ normal(0, x_sigma);
  for(i in 1:N){
    for(j in 1:J){
      mu[i,j] = beta[j] + alpha[j] * x[i];
      y[i,j] ~ normal(mu[i,j], sigma[j]);
    }
  }
}
'
fit <-stan(model_code = fact_model,data =df2,cores=2, chains=2, iter = 1000)
```

It gives me a nice estimation of the factor and `alpha` and `beta` parameters. Nevertheless, it has a bad chain convergence:

```
Warning messages:
1: There were 33 divergent transitions after warmup. See
http://mc-stan.org/misc/warnings.html#divergent-transitions-after-warmup
to find out why this is a problem and how to eliminate them. 
2: There were 2 chains where the estimated Bayesian Fraction of Missing Information was low. See
http://mc-stan.org/misc/warnings.html#bfmi-low 
3: Examine the pairs() plot to diagnose sampling problems
 
4: The largest R-hat is 1.18, indicating chains have not mixed.
Running the chains for more iterations may help. See
http://mc-stan.org/misc/warnings.html#r-hat 
5: Bulk Effective Samples Size (ESS) is too low, indicating posterior means and medians may be unreliable.
Running the chains for more iterations may help. See
http://mc-stan.org/misc/warnings.html#bulk-ess 
6: Tail Effective Samples Size (ESS) is too low, indicating posterior variances and tail quantiles may be unreliable.
Running the chains for more iterations may help. See
http://mc-stan.org/misc/warnings.html#tail-ess
```

As I understand it happens because of covariance and I should use `cholesky_decompose` approach. Unfortunately, my math background is rather poor to understand examples, which I found.

**Could You help me with a link to a SIMPLE example, or write it here?**

I may imagine another source of bad MCMC results. It is badly constrained factor loadings vector `alpha`. I defined it as `unit_vector[J] alpha`. As you may simply revert signs, it will be nice to be able to constrain somehow `alpha[1]>0`. This is not optimal solution when `alpha[1]` is close to zero. Better solution wil be to constrain `sum(alpha)>0`. I am new in STAN, so I need help with these constrains. In other words:

**Could you help me to add in my model constrains for `alpha`: `alpha[1]>0` or `sum(alpha)>0`?**

## Update:

I found a way for `alpha[1]>0` or `sum(alpha)>0`:

`alpha[1]~exponential(1)` or `sum(alpha)~exponential(1)`
but chains are still bad.

Comment: Please explain how you know it "did not work" and *how* it failed to work.

Comment: @whuber I've changed the question. Have I described my problems in sufficient detail?